# How do I clear my agent's inventory?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I can clear my inventory with `/clear @s` but I can't do the same with my agent because `/clear @c` returns an error, saying that the target selector is not a player.

Is there a workaround?

I know I can use `agent.drop_all()` from Python, but I don't want to have random tiles everywhere.